# Writing query to normalize a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, normalization

I need to write queries in order to normalize the table.

The table I currently have has these attributes, table name `dbo.oldTable`:

```
CUS_ID  STATE   CITY    ZIP     CUS_PHONE   CUS_NAME
1       OH      ABC     11111   1111111111  G
2       IL      DEG     33212   1233123123  H
3       CA      ETE     55555   6666666666  E
//many many more lines of data
...................
```

What I want to achieve here is to create a new table named `territory` and this table will have columns `STATE`,`CITY`, and `ZIP`.

So far I wrote the following query but apparently it generated a lot of rows and I cannot find a connection with the original table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Territory
(STATE nvarchar(255), CITY nvarchar(255),ZIP nvarchar(255));

INSERT INTO dbo.Territory(STATE,CITY,ZIP)
SELECT STATE,CITY,ZIP FROM dbo.oldTable;
```

Is this the right way to do the normaliaztion? I am on MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. Your original table does not appear to be denormalized. But then it seems like maybe that is part of a table named inventory in which case it extremely denormalized. If you want any real help normalizing your data structures you should post the entire table structures.

Comment: @SeanLange It is, it has information about the customer mixed with information about the territory

Comment: Why wouldn't you normalize to a table of `States` and a table of `Cities` (as M. Ali and I typed at the same time)? [Zone Improvement Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code) codes are, unfortunately, much stranger than you might think.

Comment: @Lamak from the little snippet posted that could easily be the customer master table. If I had a state table I would make the state code be the foreign key. Just saying that depending on what that table really holds it may or may not be normalized.

Comment: There's probably no need to use Unicode(NVARCHAR) on State, or City.Varchar should be fine. Remember you want as narrow as possible datatypes. I would make State CHAR(2), Zip INT, cus_phone BIGINT. Also you should split CUS_name into FirstName and LastName to make it normalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Territory
(id int identity, STATE nvarchar(255), CITY nvarchar(255),ZIP nvarchar(255));

create table dbo.customer (CUS_ID int identity, territoryid int,        CUS_PHONE varchar (12),  CUS_NAME varchar(25))

alter table dbo.customer  
ADD CONSTRAINT t_id,
FOREIGN KEY (territoryid) 
REFERENCES   dbo.Territory(id)
```

Any territoryid must refer to a value that already exists in the id column in dbo.territory.

```
To insert a new customer:
insert into dbo.customer (territoryid, cus_phone, cus_name) values (3,'212-555-1212','Mary')
```

Comment: M. Alis solution is correct (in terms of 3rd order form) but sometimes too much normalization (like most things) is not necessarily the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure how Zip codes work in USA, but assuming One state can have multiple Cities and A city can have multiple Zip codes I would do the following to normalize the database

```
CREATE TABLE States
( 
  StateID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
, StateName NVARCHAR(100)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE City
( 
  CityID  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
, StateID INT REFERENCES States(StateID)
, City    NVARCHAR(100)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Zip
( 
  ZipID  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
, CityID INT REFERENCES City(CityID)
, Zip    NVARCHAR(100)
)
GO
```

And now you Customers Tables will look something like .......

```
CUS_ID  ZIP_ID     CUS_PHONE   CUS_NAME
1       11111      1111111111     G
2       33212      1233123123     H
3       55555      6666666666     E
```

Comment: I understand. But what I need is to put ZIP, STATE, and CITY in one table

Comment: well this would  violate the rules of normalization itself, One state can have multiple cities so you will be repeating a state as many cities that state has plus as many as Zip codes each city has. Mind you the whole purpose of normalization is to reduce data redundancy, what you are suggesting , you are better off to leave data as it is.

Comment: In the US (and other parts of the world) a little bit of denormalization is fine, especially when it comes to customer address data.

Comment: @SeanLange true but if someone has gone through the trouble of asking a question on SO about normalization, person deserves an answer about the best practices :)

Comment: Agreed 100%. Wasn't suggesting anything other than that. I was agreeing with you that the original structure might be fine.